# How can I add one click listener for the parent container and all the children?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a view hierarchy in one of my layouts as follows (simplified XML to make the issue clear):

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/top_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">   
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >  
               // 2 childern here  
         </LinearLayout>  
         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            >
           // children here   
         </RelativeLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to do an action on click of the anywhere in this view.
Adding a click listener on the `top_container` doesn't work unless I click it somewhere on the top where I don't touch any of the child views.
Is there any way to do it without needing to add a click listener to all of the children (which would call the same handler)?

**Update:**
Wrapping everything in a FrameLayout did not solve it. If I click anywhere in the RelativeLayout the click listener is still not fired

Comment: Are you writing any click listener for your child views?

Comment: @Drv:You are right. There was a click listener in one of the child views. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Jim Isn't my answer fit your requirement?

Comment: @Divers:The thing is that your answer works but my current layout structure also works. The problem was that there was a click listener in one of the children that caused the problem. Unless your point was that the way you define it is better than my definition in which case please elaborate on that so that I understand it (was not clear from your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in `RelativeLayout` and put empty FrameLayout Above all your views, e.g.:

```
    <RelativeLayout>
      <Your views....>

      <FrameLayout 
         android:id="@+id/top_layer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height ="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

and then:
```

`findViewById(R.id.top_layer).setOnClickListener(....)`

In case if you'd like to pass click event on a layer bellow (to your views), you can use `addOnItemTouchListener` instead of `ClickListener`